# How to save a worksheet in Excel to CSV using VBA and file saved as User's name and Date?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello and hi everyone.

I'm sorry if what I asked right now sounds dumb or stupid, but I'm relatively new to VBA's and not really fluent with it.

Now, I have a form for user to input report on incident happened at their workplace and I manage to save the Data worksheet as csv but now, I want to automatically save the sheet as username and time the csv printed.

Here is what my code look like.

```
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet
Dim xStrDate As String


Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PartsData")
xStrDate = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add

shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wbkExport.SaveAs FileName:=xStrDate,"C:\temp\IncidentDatabase.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

and when I try to run the code, this happened

[image]

it's highlighted on this part -

```
wbkExport.SaveAs FileName:=xStrDate,"C:\temp\IncidentDatabase.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

I have read some of almost similar question but found no answer. Please help me.
Thank you.
Regard.

Comment: use `wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:=xStrDate & "C:\temp\IncidentDatabase.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV`  remove `,` replace with `&` It will remove syntax error

Comment: I think `wbkExport.SaveAs FileName:=xStrDate,"C:\temp\IncidentDatabase.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV` should be changed to `wbkExport.SaveAs FileName:="C:\temp\IncidentDatabase" & xStrDate & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV` for proper working

Comment: Please see my edit to have some space and dash between filename and datestring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think code line

```
wbkExport.SaveAs FileName:=xStrDate,"C:\temp\IncidentDatabase.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

should be changed to

```
 wbkExport.SaveAs FileName:="C:\temp\IncidentDatabase - " & xStrDate & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

for proper working

Answer (score 2):

Copy the worksheet without providing a location. This creates a new workbook with the copied worksheet as the only worksheet.

The ENVIRON function can retrieve environment variables like the user name.

```
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()

    Dim fn As String

    fn = environ("USERNAME") & "-" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PartsData").Copy

    With activeworkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = false
        .SaveAs FileName:="C:\temp\" & fn, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        Application.DisplayAlerts = true
        .close savechanges:=false
    end with

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see `.SaveAs` properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas).

The first argument is the name & the second is the file type.

```
Dim loc As String
loc = "C:\temp\"
xStrDate = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")

wbkExport.SaveAs loc & wbkExport.Name &  xStrDate, xlCSV
```